# Getting a time control working using backgroundworker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have an application that grabs data to a csv file and the programs grabs the data once every 5 seconds. the problem is that i cant do any other operations while this happening in the background. I'm using a timer to get the job done.

I found out abt the `backgroundworker` control and I tried to use it and I set the `RunWorkerAsync` in the form deceleration method(after `initializeComponent`) but it doesent get started out. I have given the coding for backgroundworker below.

What needs to be corrected here? nd if this is not the right aproach, what is the best way to get the background process happening while im being able to procede with the other forma activities.Thanks

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //int a = (int)(e.Argument);
    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        timerQuote.Enabled = true;
        timerQuote.Start();
    }
}


private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("grabbing is terminated");
    }
}

//Form decleration
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Timer` must be started on the UI thread, or it will fail silent. Also there's no need to set the enabled property yourself - when you call the `Start` method it will change to true.

An alternative could be:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var t = new Timer();
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(GrabData);
        t.Interval = 5000;
        t.Start();
    }

    void GrabData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // get and return data
        });

        // do something with the data.Result
    }
}
```